# How to get host/port from mongoose Connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am connecting to MongoDb by mongoose v5.7.1 on NodeJS and need get the Connection's host and port , but the TypeScript raise this error *"Property 'host' does not exist on type 'Connection'.ts(2339)"* when I try like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
...
private database: typeof mongoose
...
database = await mongoose.connect(mongoDbUri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
database.connection.host
```

But, on Mongoose documentation, the *Connection* class have the properties **host** and **port**:

> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-host

Follow my *package.json*:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1",
    "validator": "^11.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.42",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.18",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^5.2.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  }
```

What is wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrong types. Bypass by writing `(conn.connection as any).host`